# How to convert RGBA files to RGB

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition

I am doing a tutorial on making a CNN for image-recognition. I have downloaded a bunch of pictures from the internet per class. I gave them all the extension .jpg.

When I am trying to train my model I get the error-message:

```
Userwarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images
```

Can I fix this or did I use the wrong type of pictures? It seems that when I make a model without the imagedatagenerator that it is no problem, but if I do use it than I get this error message.

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the way you are reading the input images needs correction.

Usually, TensorFlow models consume images in numpy nd array format. Try refining the image reading pipeline and feed images as numpy nd array. Give a look at this [domo](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification)

Comment: Thank you, That is a good demo. I will try some things from this demo. Hope that it helps

Comment: your demo example uses `train_gen`, o/p of flow_from_directory and still it gives error in my case. I think error is something else.